# Water pressure low after hose was left on overnight

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well-pump, well

The water pressure inside my house went way down and stayed down after the hose was left on overnight.  It's been a while now and the water pressure is still low (useable but low).  The air pressure on the pump hovers between 40 and 50psi and we are served by well water.  I hope there was no permanent damage done by leaving the hose on for that long.  Anyone have any suggestions?

[image: Photo of the pump in all its glory]

[image: Closeup of the model details]

Comment: Does this mean the pump isn't shutting off? An easy way to help isolate is to close the valve to the rest of your house. If it comes up to pressure and shuts off right away, you have something else using water (could be a leak). If not, I'd suspect as @Bob suggests the well is low. You might just want to try shutting off the pump power for a while to give your pump a break (and let the well catch up).

Comment: The pump is definitely shutting off.  I'm going to try and not use the water for a day or so and see if it can catch up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd guess that the recovery rate on your well is sufficient for your daily use, but not for the extended used that occured with the hose.  As a result, the water level in your well has probably dropped to the point that the intake tube isn't completely submerged, so it's drawing less water.  If you can reduce your water usage for a few days, it will likely recover.